# What is a Chameleon word™?

Tags: word-property

<sub>*This is in the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

If a word conforms to a certain rule, I call it a Chameleon Word™. Use the following examples to find the rule:

| Chameleon Words ™ | Not Chameleon Words ™ |
| --- | --- |
| Ours | Theirs |
| Coin | Bill |
| Bite | Nibble |
| Bras | Knickers |
| Cent | Dollar |
| Trombone | Trumpet |
| Peter | Paul |
| Singe | Burn |

CSV version:

```
Chameleon Words ™, Not Chameleon Words 
Ours, Theirs 
Coin, Bill
Bite, Nibble
Bras, Knickers
Cent, Dollar
Trombone, Trumpet
Peter, Paul
Singe, Burn
```

Comment: _Mon dieu_! The BITE and PETER words are pretty much in line with the Kit-Ginevra hunour we've learned to love. `:)`

Comment: @MOehm And this is without mentioning KNICKERS (niqueur) and BURN (burne)...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A Chameleon Word is

> a word that is valid (and has different definitions) in both French and English.

Explanation

> The French translations are:
>  ours = bear
>  coin = corner
>  bite = slang for male reproductive organ
>  bras = arms
>  cent = hundred
>  trombone = paperclip
>  peter = to fart
>  singe = monkey

It's called a Chameleon Word because

> its definition can change based on its environment, similar to a chameleon's skin color.

Comment: That was my first impression too, but DOLLAR is a perfectly valid French noun and PAUL is a French firstname. Then I was about to propose "French words that mean something completely different in English" but TROMBONE and CENT don't fit the definition either.

Comment: There is no **language** tag for this puzzle, for this answer to be valid. Is it not ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand why "French words that mean something completely different in English" doesn't work? It sure seems to me that trombone and cent fit

Comment: @ColdFrog We use the exact same words in French for TROMBONE (the instrument) and CENT (the money). To my knowledge, despite their common spelling, the other six chameleon words have no common meaning in French and in English.

Comment: Ohhhhhh, I see - my assumption was that the listed translations were the only one :P

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay there doesn’t have to be a language tag. Lots of puzzles such as this won’t add a particular tag as it will make it too obvious

Answer (score 0):

A Chameleon Word is

> one that has one or more homophones (words that sound the same when pronounced, but have different spellings), whereas their counterparts do not.

That Is,

> Ours   -  hours
>  Coin   -  quoin
>  Bite    -  byte
>  Trombone   - to be explored...
>  Singe   - synge
>  Bras - Brass
>  Cent - Scent
>  Peter  - to be explored...

Comment: What about Paul/pall?

Comment: And theres/theirs?

Comment: Ah too easy for the brilliant minds here!